# Google online account is always asking for access grant

Tags: online-accounts

When I open my user session in Ubuntu 12.10, System Settings tray icon in top panel is always in red mentioning that some online account needs internet access grant.

Yet, It's always **Google** and only Google.

I granted it access many times but it's not persistent. Either connected to Internet or not, this behavior remains.

This being a bug; does anyone have some workaround?

[image: Google 12.10]

[image: Google 12.10 Bug]

Comment: Why was this closed?  It's very relevant.

Comment: @AndrewMyers I think it was closed because it is a bug.
I asked the question hoping someone could reveal a workaround, while the bug is being addressed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's definitely **not** the correct behaviour.

There is already a bug reported for a similar situation, but not enough information has been provided unfortunately. If you could help by providing the missing information, that would help us a lot in finding out what's wrong:

https://launchpad.net/bugs/1029289

Comment: I reacted in the bug story.

Comment: Thank you for point the bug report link. I think that the problem is when using the same Google account on more Ubuntu PCs...